# Conditional formatting only values in range in Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have these values in A1:C16 in Excel:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NA | NA | NA |
| 3,18E-04 | NA | NA |
| 3,75E-03 | 1,03E-10 | NA |
| 5,67E+01 | 7,95E+02 | 9,61E-16 |
| 9,25E-01 | 9,85E-02 | 2,04E-01 |
| 7,80E-02 | 1,10E-03 | 3,04E-01 |
| 5,29E-60 | 1,09E-144 | 1,61E-251 |
| 3,59E-43 | 9,07E-93 | 5,62E-230 |
| 1,16E+09 | 4,23E+08 | 1,43E+09 |
| 8,52E-01 | 7,71E-01 | 6,95E-01 |
| 9,80E+09 | 3,68E+08 | 2,79E-04 |
| 2,21E-01 | 9,84E-01 | 4,99E-02 |
| 4,88E+00 | 6,18E-02 | 1,89E-02 |
| 1,67E-03 | 3,50E-04 | 9,68E-03 |
| 6,31E-29 | 5,41E-58 | 5,04E-98 |
| 8,39E-14 | 8,68E-24 | 2,84E-15 |

What I need to do is to colour scale only values between the minimum value (1,61E-251) and 0,05. Can anyone help me?

Comment: this is probably suited better for https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 2 rules of conditional formatting. The first will be formula based and (assuming you are using the range specified in the sample) will use this formula:

```
=A1>0,05
```

Note that A1 is the first top left cell of your range and its address is not absolute. This will make the conditional formatting focus on each cell (not just on cell A1). You can set the format according to your needs.

The second rule will be a 2-scale color value based conditional formatting. You'll set the first color to the minimum and the second color to number 0,05.

Be sure to respect the rules' order. If you swap them, they won't work in the same way.